# OpenGL on Android: Any conflicts when calling OpenGL functions in both Java and C++?

Tags: java, c++, android, opengl-es, native

In my application, I'm using a 3rd party custom view that calls OpenGL functions in Java, and I'm also calling OpenGL functions in my native C++ code.

Should this be a problem?

Is there any risk that they could be called at the same time?

What is the threading order of OpenGL calls across java/c++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should not be a problem, as long as you know what you're doing. The OpenGL Java bindings in Android basically just call the same c++ function. There's not more logic in those calls. So you can basically think of those calls in the same way as if they were direct c++ code.

The problem that you are more likely to run into will be that OpenGL is not threadsafe if you have only one context. So if two threads try to call gl methods in the same context (which is usually the case in just a single app) this will cause problems. You can forego these problems by calling eglMakeCurrent, to make your current thread the current OpenGL thread. And then you can make your gl calls as usual.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access single OpenGL context from different threads. But it's legal to mix C++ and Java, the latter are just wrappers on native calls.

Answer (score 1):

There is always problems with calling the same function from multiple threads if that function modifies some global object.

You can call OpenGL from both Java and C++, unsure if it has to be in the same thread though.
In a game I wrote I did all the rendering in C++ but loading of textures in Java (since java has access to the R class), the C++ class would call a java function which loaded the textures.